# Gsuite add-on : On Install - Sorry, unable to open the file at this time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I've created an add-on using the google app script and published it on gsuite marketplace.

[image: Install button for the app]

When the browser has multiple users logged in and when I try to install the app, I get this message:

Sorry, unable to open the file at this time
[image: Install issue]

This only happens when there are multiple gmail users logged into the same browser.

I'm not sure how to solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the full link of the page that you are trying to open? Your issue looks similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045209/google-drive-page-not-found-sorry-unable-to-open-the-file-at-this-time and ````/u/0```` or ````/u/1/```` may have been appended to the link.

Comment: @CarlosM the issue you have mentioned is for deploying a web app using google app script. My problem is related to an add-on in the gsuite workspace marketplace. I've also added a picture of the install button which is causing this issue.

Comment: The add-on installation still redirected to a script.google.com/macros/u/ link, which caused the issue in Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

I might as well post this as an answer, as the problematic link is already displayed on the image:

When you have multiple accounts logged in to a single browser, the resolved link appends `/u/0/`, `/u/1/`, so on... to differentiate which account is to be accessed. However, it is maybe an unresolved bug, but it causes the "unable to open file" message to appear.

Referencing from this SO post, [Google Drive Page Not Found - Sorry, unable to open the file at this time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045209/google-drive-page-not-found-sorry-unable-to-open-the-file-at-this-time?noredirect=1&lq=1), the easiest workaround is to remove the `/u/0/` or similar string from the resolved link.

Comment: I know that the add-on is redirecting to the script.google.com/macros/u/  LINK. 

There's no way one can edit this link and remove the /u/0 in a published add-on using code. It is handled by google's marketplace SDK.  

What I want is an answer to how it can be fixed.

Comment: Hi Aman Jain, Did you manage to solve the issue ? We are facing the same unfortunately. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @AmanJain sorry for posting twice but I didn't tag you correctly

Comment: No, I wasn't been able to solve this issue. @JulienB